# Как перевернуть число?

Tags: javascript

Вспомнил одну задачу, нужно написать функцию возвращаю число в обратном порядке, без преобразования в строку. К примеру 5921 -> 1295. Никак не дойдет как это сделать

Comment: рекурсией или циклом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А так устроит ответ? без преобразования в `string`:

```js
var x = 5921;
var y = 0;
for(; x; x = Math.floor(x / 10)) {
    y *= 10;
    y += x % 10;
}
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Пока `num !== 0` берем последнюю цифру от `num`, делим этот `num` на 10, добавляем порядок к `result` и плюсуем последнюю цифру к `result`.

```js
var num = 5921;

function getReversedNum(num) {
  let result = 0;
  while (num) {
    result = result * 10 + num % 10;
    num = Math.floor(num / 10);
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(getReversedNum(num));
```

Comment: Получше моего варианта)

Answer (score 0):

Не лучший вариант, но рабочий:

```js
function reverseInt(number) {
  var result = '';
  
  while(number>0){
   result = result + (number%10);
   number = parseInt(number/10);
  }
  
  return result;
}

var number = 5921;
console.log(reverseInt(number));
```

Comment: Тут есть преобразование в строку.

Answer (score 0):

Или так:

```js
function reverse(num, r = 0){
    if(!num) return r;
    r =  r * 10  + num % 10;
    return reverse(Math.floor( num / 10), r);
}
console.log(reverse(12345));
```

Comment: _без преобразования в строку_

Comment: @Grundy не увидел

Comment: убрать тернарный оператор `(r ? r * 10 : 0)` можно использовав значение параметра по умолчанию: `function reverse(num, r=0){`

Comment: @Grundy, исправил, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
revert = num => {
  let i = 0, result=0;
  for(let r=1; r<num; r=10**++i) result+=(((num-num%r)/r)%10)/r;
  return result*(10**(i-1));
}
console.log([321,48735,90008].map(revert))
```